# C Program Displays multiple prints

Tags: c, variables, debugging, output

i have written an c code to calculate  electric bill 
its giving the output i expect but it repeats the output too much i have tried to debug it but can't seem to know where did i mistake can someone review my code please ?
i just want the first output to be visible only not all of those results

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    GetInputs();
    CalConsumCharge();
    CalExtraCharges();
    DispBill();
}

void GetInputs(){
    int unittot;
    int unit1;
    int Prev_Cons;
    printf("Enter Previous units consumption: ");
    scanf("%d",&Prev_Cons);
    printf("Enter the units consumed: ");
    scanf("%d",&unittot);
    unit1 = unittot - Prev_Cons;
    CalConsumCharge(unit1);
}

void CalConsumCharge(int unit){
    int total = 0;
    if(unit<=50){
        total = (unit*22);
    }
    else if(unit<=100){
        total = ((50*22)+(unit-50)*30);
    }
    else if(unit<=200){
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(unit-100)*36);
    }
    else if(unit<=350){
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(100*36)+(unit-200)*70);
    }
    else if(unit<=650){
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(100*36)+(150*70)+(unit-350)*90);
    }
    else if(unit<=1000){
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(100*36)+(150*70)+(300*90)+((unit-650)*135));
    }
    else{
        total = ((unit*145));
    }

    CalExtraCharges(total);
}

void CalExtraCharges(int total){
    int total1;
    total = total/100;
    if(total>=2000){
        total1 = total + 10 +20;
    }
    else{
        total1 = total +10;
    }
    DispBill(total1);
}

void DispBill(int total1){
    if(total1>=2000){
        printf("A penalty Charge was Placed Because your bill is over 2000 L.E");
        printf("Bill amount is: %d L.E",total1);
    }
    else if(total1<2000) {
        printf("your bill is : %d L.E",total1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This doesn't look valid as presented because `CalConsumCharge()` has no parameter, but basically calling `GetInputs` in `main` kicks off a chain that calls all the other functions, so you don't need to call them explicitly again in `main`. Chaining all the functions is poor design, though, so consider returning values back to main so each function can work decoupled from the others. In other words, sometimes you might want to get input without computing anything, and sometimes you want to compute things without showing a bill. But the current design can't support that use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this code needs a lot of love and attention.  I am surprised you can compile and run it.  You main function only needs to call GetInputs() as that calls all the other functions.

I refactored the main and the rest of the code for cleanliness.  I didn't change any logic and it ran fine.  Take a look:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void DispBill(int total1)
{

    if(total1>=2000)
    {
        printf("A penalty Charge was Placed Because your bill is over 2000 L.E");
        printf("Bill amount is: %d L.E",total1);
    }
    else if(total1<2000) 
    {
        printf("your bill is : %d L.E",total1);
    }
}

void CalExtraCharges(int total)
{
    int total1;
    total = total/100;

    if(total>=2000)
    {
        total1 = total + 10 +20;
    }
    else
    {
        total1 = total +10;
    }

    DispBill(total1);
}

void CalConsumCharge(int unit)
{
    int total = 0;

    if(unit<=50)
    {
        total = (unit*22);
    }
    else if(unit<=100)
    {
        total = ((50*22)+(unit-50)*30);
    }
    else if(unit<=200)
    {
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(unit-100)*36);
    }
    else if(unit<=350)
    {
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(100*36)+(unit-200)*70);
    }
    else if(unit<=650)
    {
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(100*36)+(150*70)+(unit-350)*90);
    }
    else if(unit<=1000)
    {
        total = ((50*22)+(50*30)+(100*36)+(150*70)+(300*90)+((unit-650)*135));
    }
    else
    {
    total = ((unit*145));
    }

    CalExtraCharges(total);
}

void GetInputs(void)
{
    int unitTotal;
    int unitOne;
    int Prev_Cons;

    printf("Enter Previous units consumption: ");
    scanf("%d",&Prev_Cons);

    printf("Enter the units consumed: ");
    scanf("%d",&unitTotal);

    unitOne = unitTotal - Prev_Cons;

    CalConsumCharge(unitOne);
}

int main()
{
    GetInputs();
}
```

Here is my output:

[image: Here is the output!]

Comment: so its only important to call the function once ?

Comment: i can notice that you only removed the functions from main and only left the GetInputs function am i correct ?

Comment: Correct! You only want to call GetInputs once.  Since it calls all the other functions.  If you call it multiple times you will get wrong output.

Comment: hey may i ask why did you type void again in " void GetInputs(void) "  why didnt it be "void GetInputs() "  ??

Comment: The function GetInputs does not take any input arguments.  I like to clearly note that in the function declaration/definition with void.  That way it is 100% clear what the function inputs and returns are.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile your code, then see what happen (errors, warning).

Firstly, you forgot to declare the functions. Add the declarations below before implementation of the main function.

```
void GetInputs();
void CalConsumCharge(int unit);
void CalExtraCharges(int total);
void DispBill(int total1);
```

Secondly, because you call the `CalConsumCharge` in `GetInputs`,  `CalExtraCharges` in `CalConsumCharge`, etc, so you just call `GetInputs` in the main function is enough.

```
int main(){
    GetInputs();
}
```

If you want to call many functions as your code in the main function, you should return the value at the end of each function as below:

The declaration of all function:

```
int GetInputs();
int CalConsumCharge(int unit);
int CalExtraCharges(int total);
void DispBill(int total1);
```

The, correcting a bit for each function

```
int GetInputs() {
   ...
   unit1 = unittot - Prev_Cons;
   return unit1;
}
```

```
int CalConsumCharge(int unit) {
    ...
    else{
        total = ((unit*145));
    }
    return total;
}
```

```
int CalExtraCharges(int total) {
   ...
   else{
        total1 = total +10;
    }
    return total1;
}
```

Then, in main function:

```
int main () {
   int unit1 = GetInputs();
   int total = CalConsumCharge(unit1);
   int total1 = CalExtraCharges(total);
   DisBill(total1);

   return 0;
}
```